# Firebase "passwordless sign in" link is hidden on subsequent login attempts

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Problem in bold; everything else is background, discussion, and solution attempts.

I'm using the Firebase method `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailLink` — and the *first* time the email is sent, it works as intended.

**The problem occurs when the user signs out, and later signs in again.**

**In that case, the actual link gets hidden by the email client's propensity to hide repeated text.**  (Since the sign-in message Firebase sends is the same each time, most of it gets truncated in, for instance, Gmail, after the first message in the thread).

As I'm testing my login experience, I've had users confused as to how to sign in due to not seeing the link.  Since truncated text is usually a signature, or quoted, or irrelevant, they don't know to click the "..." to expand the portion of the message containing the link.

This seems like a major problem, but I know that sign-in-by-link is quite common, and I'm failing to see the solution.

Since I can't control the behavior of the user's email client, I'm trying to find a solution on my end.  One thing I tried was to customize the sign-in email so that it would always contain a random string *below* the sign-in link in the email, to hopefully sidestep the email client's heuristic for when to truncate text.  Unfortunately, according to Firebase console, customizing the sign-in text is disallowed for spam reasons.  Similarly, I'd could add a unique identifier to the email subject, but again, I don't see a way to achieve this programatically because of the same restriction.

Of course, I also looked at the docs, and didn't see mention of this case.

So, **is there a way to ensure that the passwordless sign-in link is actually *visible* in the email that Firebase sends?  If not, am I missing something basic about the use of passwordless auth?**

Thanks for working through this with me.

Comment: There might not be anything you can do directly, so I suggest sending feedback to Firebase support to say what isn't working well for you, and explain exactly the conditions that can be used to reproduce the problem, so that the Firebase staff can see it for themselves.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I'll certainly report it, as you suggest, but gosh, that's a shame -- must be confusing a ton of users who think they never received the link!